# Intermediate Value theorem with a function on R

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Does anyone know how to answer this? I am really struggling with it

Assume f : [0, 1] → R is continuous with f(0) = f(1).

Show that there exists a point c ∈ [0, 1/2] with f(c) = f(c + 1/2).

Comment: Consider the function $h(x):=f(x)-f(x+\frac12)$ and compare $h(0),h(1)$.

Comment: IVT tells us that there exists a $c \in \left( 0, \frac{1}{2} \right)$ such
that $f (c) = f \left( c + \frac{1}{2} \right)$ if $f (0) < f \left( c +
\frac{1}{2} \right) < f \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)$ or $f (0) > f \left( c +
\frac{1}{2} \right) > f \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)$. Can you show that this is
true?

Comment: duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053764/f-is-a-continuous-function-from-0-1-to-mathbbr-s-t-f0-f1-prov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to this is to define a new function $g : [0,1/2] \to \mathbb{R}$
\begin{align}
g(x) = f(x+1/2) - f(x)
\end{align}
Note that $g$ is also continuous.
Plug in values $0$ and $1/2$,
\begin{align}
g(0) &= f(1/2) - f(0)\\
\\
g(1/2) &= f(1) - f(1/2)\\
g(1/2) &= f(0) - f(1/2) \\
g(1/2) &= -g(0)
\end{align}
So, since $g$ is a continuous function and $0$ lies between $g(0)$ and $g(1/2)$, by the by intermediate value theorem we can deduce that $\exists c \in [0,1/2]$ such that $g(c) = 0 $
Final step is to write $g$ in terms of $f$ again. We have:
\begin{align}
\exists c \in [0,1/2] \text{ with } g(c) &= f(c+1/2)-f(c) = 0\\
\Rightarrow f(c+1/2) = f(c)
\end{align}